# Google Map Autocomplete Wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, google-maps

I have a page on which there is google map auto-complete enabled in Neighborhood field for filtering search results. I wanted to have auto-complete also on the City field. Tried and failed desperately
[The url of the page.](http://searchworkplace.com/properties-search-results/?sort=newest&search_city=Mumbai&search_lat=19.0759837&search_lng=72.87765590000004&search_type=22)

C/o  Please click on the filter your results toggle on the top right to see the fields.

```
if($('#search_city').length > 0) {
    var city= document.getElementById('search_city');
    var cityAuto= new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(city);
    google.maps.event.addListener(cityAuto, 'place_changed', function() {
        var place = cityAuto.getPlace();
        $('#search_city').blur();
        setTimeout(function() { $('#search_city').val(place.address_components[0].short_name); }, 1);

        return false;
    });
```

}

Comment: There is no event wired up to your city text box.  Where are you wiring up the neighborhood box?  Show some code to get help, please.

Comment: @SeanKendle Hi, I updated my question. if you could please look into this. This is the exact same code for Neighborhood field but doesn't work when applied to City field. P.S: There is another field with same id (search_city) in some other page. Does that create a problem by any chance?

Comment: Why are you mixing jQuery with raw Javascript like `document.getElementById`?

Comment: add this line after the `var city` line, I suspect it's undefined... `console.log(city);`

Comment: i will look into this.. and let you guys know. been caught up with some things. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's just some general advice, and it may help you if your object is undefined.

Change your code to true jQuery, and cache your object in a variable.  Also, it's good practice to preface all jQuery wrapped objects with a `$`.

```
//if your code isn't already in a document ready function, keep this.  if not, delete the following line and the last line, `});`
$(document).ready(function(){

    var $searchCity = $("#search_city"); //cache object to prevent querying for it again

    if($searchCity.length > 0) {
        //$searchCity already set, don't set it again

        var cityAuto = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete($searchCity);
        //var cityAuto = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete($searchCity[0]); //if Google wants a raw DOM object, use this line, delete the above line - the [0] gives you the DOM object from a jQuery object

        google.maps.event.addListener(cityAuto, 'place_changed', function() {
            var place = cityAuto.getPlace();
            $searchCity.blur();

            setTimeout(function() {
                $searchCity.val(place.address_components[0].short_name); 
            }, 1);

            return false;
        });
    }
});
```

Let me know if that works.